# Display commits since last merge, including commits merged in

Tags: git

I have two branches, `staging` and `live`. I have previously merged `staging` into `live`. I want a list of all commits that have occurred since I last merged `staging` into `live`, and that list should have any merge commits substituted for the list of commits that was merged in (i.e., if I merge `dev` into `staging`, I want to see the commits from `dev` that were merged in, not the merge commit). How can I dos this?

Optionally, for extra fun, tell me how to exclude commits merged into `staging` from `live` from this list.

Comment: Why do you need `merge commits` to be substituted? The commits that have been merged will show up in a regular `git log`. So just doing `git log staging..live` should be sufficient to get the commit difference between the two branches.

Comment: `git log` is listing the merge commits: "Merge branch 'dev' into staging". Upon closer inspection, I do see some commits from other branches in live..staging. It looks like Git displaying the combined history of all branches chronologically, whereas I expected it to show the merged-in commits where the merge commits are placed. But this is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

`git log staging ^live` will give you all commits that are in staging but *not* in live, i.e. those that happened in staging since the last merge to live.